# Delphi draw a closed rectangle with two rounded corners and to rectangular corners

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

How can I draw a rectangle that has two round corners and the opposite corners are rectangular corners. The shape must be closed so it can be filled with the Brush color. The Polyline method doesn't draw curved lines. Can I add the points of an Arc to the polyline points? I tried to draw a RoundRect using Canvas method and then, overlapping a rectangle over the lower round corners, but I couldn't figure out how to erase the upper line of the rectangle when drawign just the border of the shape without filling it. Note: if you think is relevant, I can add the code I used.

Sample of the desired shape:

[image]

Sample of what I got with Delphi:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to fill the shape at the same time you draw it.  You can use a series of `TCanvas.LineTo()` and `TCanvas.ArcTo()`/`TCanvas.AngleArc()` calls first to create the shape, then call `TCanvas.FloodFill()` afterwards to fill it.

Otherwise, you can overlap `TCanvas.Rectangle()` on top of `TCanvas.RoundRect()` with the same fill color, and then use `TCanvas.MoveTo()`/`TCanvas.LineTo()` to draw over the dividing line with the same fill color.

Another option would be to forget using `TCanvas` drawing methods and just use Win32 API calls instead.  Use `CreateRoundRectRgn()`, `CreateRectRgn()`, and `CombineRn()` to create a `HRGN` that has your desired shape, then use `FillRgn()` and `FrameRgn()` to draw on your `TCanvas` using that `HRGN`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The first option seems to be promising. I'll give it a try. The second option doesn't work when I want to draw the shape transparent (meaning I wan't fill it). The third option, I prefer not to implement, because I don't feel myself confident with Windows API.

Comment: Dear Remy. Turns out that using the Windows API is much easear than I thought. IMO, the Arc method, as implemented by TCanvas, is very tricky and difficult to use. Thanks a lot!